# Rails 3/Ruby 1.9.3 JSON.parse string encoding invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, mongodb, rake

As part of a rake task, I'm retrieving a JSON file which has escaped unicode characters in it (such as `\u00fc` for u with umlaut etc.) A relevant sample would be:

```
{
  "text": "f\u00fcr"
}
```

Then I try to parse it and store it into my MongoDB:

```
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port, :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https', :verify_mode => OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE) do |http|
  data = http.request(request).body
end

json = JSON.parse(data)
name = "my-data"
obj = {}
obj["name"] = name
obj["data"] = json

# assume db connection vars such as @connection are set
stored =  @collection.find_one({"name" => name})
if stored
  stored['data'] = obj['data']
  @collection.update({"_id" => stored["_id"]}, stored)  
else
  @collection.insert(obj)
end
```

As soon as I inspect the `json["text"]` variable from this line: `json = JSON.parse(data)` it looks like this: `"f\xB8\xC5r"` which then MongoDB complains about:

> *** BSON::InvalidStringEncoding Exception: String not valid UTF-8

I've set the magic top-comment in all my files (it's set as part of a rake task):

```
#-- encoding: UTF-8
```

I've also set my internal and external encoding in my environment.rb to UTF-8

I'm not very knowledgeable where encodings are concerned but I've spent the past day googling and it's not got me anywhere. Does anyone know what this issue might be caused by? It's worth noting that doing this in a simple test ruby doesn't reproduce this issue but as soon as I run it through Rake it breaks.

---

I've also tried storing the unparsed JSON retrieved directly into MongoDB and then parsing it to display it in a view. As soon as the view tries to render `text` I get the great:

> invalid byte sequence in UTF-8

Trying to force the encoding to UTF-8 doesn't get rid of the error. Encoding it with `encode` to UTF-8 gives the same outcome. Trying to force the encoding to something else then encoding it to UTF-8:

```
text.force_encoding('ascii-8bit').encode('utf-8')
```

This renders either the wrong thing ('H-') or nothing at all, depending on what OS/environment I'm looking at the page with (Windows 7/Windows 8 is what I've noticed the difference on).

---

**Setup:** 
Ruby 1.9.3,
Rails 3.0.4,
Rake 0.9.2,
json (gem) 1.6.1,
mongo (gem) 1.4.0,
bson & bson_ext (gems) 1.4.0,
MongoDB 2.6.7,
Amazon Linux AMI 2014.09

Comment: That should have been parsed as \xc3\xbc - it's the JSON.parse step that's gone wrong I think

Comment: Could you please provide minimal example to reproduce your problem? I have tried to reproduce locally but in my case all works fine.